# How to test conformity with a protocol with associatedType in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I've been trying to do some code that allows the user to "attach" a specific model to a specific cell. I intended to do that with protocols and the `associatedType` approach.

Here's the plan:

Cells conform to `MTZSectionRowConfigurable` when they can display data, but they do not necessarily need to:

```
public protocol MTZSectionRowConfigurable {
    associatedtype T: MTZSectionRowModel
    func configure(with model: T?)
}
```

By using `typealias`, they allow the user to define which model they're going to represent:

```
class SignOutCell: UITableViewCell, MTZSectionRowConfigurable {
    typealias T = SignOutModel
    var redLabel: UILabel!
    // ...
    func configure(with model: SignOutCellModel?) {
        self.redLabel.text = model?.text
    }
}
```

Models simply conform to `MTZSectionRowModel` to explicitly declare compatibility.

However, since representing models is optional, I need to check the cells for supporting them before calling the configure method. This is done on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if let cell = cell as? MTZSectionRowConfigurable {
    cell.configure(with: sectionRow.model)
}
```

*In the example above, `sectionRow.model` is of `MTZSectionRowModel?` type.*

The code above **does not compile**. It generates the infamous:

> *"Protocol 'MTZSectionRowConfigurable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"*

I've tried to check if the cell responds to `#selector` as well, but unfortunately the same error applies.

Is there any way to make this code work? Am I missing something? I can  drop the `associatedType`, implement the methods on every cell with a broad `MTZSectionRowModel`, but then I would need to cast inside every implementation, but that wouldn't be the optimal solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do and I have done it myself.  However, it is a little more involved than what you are doing now.  The answer you seek it within Andy Matuschak's [gist](https://gist.github.com/andymatuschak/f1e1691fa1a327468f8e).

In keeping with best practices for SO answers, I will explain why this works.  Let's start with the end.  `cellForRow...` this is the `objc func` and it needs to return `UITableViewCell?`.  So we already know, we are going to lose type information at some point (ie. your `SignOutCell` class is not what is returned, it is its superclass, `UITableViewCell`).  Given that we end up with a `UITableViewCell`, how can we do what you are wanting to do and produce a `SignOutCell` and configure it?  The answer lies in defining the completion handler in the `CellFactory` that Andy describes in his gist (linked herein). Then he uses a `bridgedDataSource` to convert from one cell type to another.  I customized his code to allow for returning 4 different types of cells depending on the input parameters.  For example, my `UITableViewController` may contain 4 `UITableViewCell` items, each one could be very distinct in its layout and data model.  I would parameterize `CellFactory` to accept an `enum CellType` where I pre-defined the 4 types.  Then, within the cell factory I use `switch cellType` to setup the cell (at this point I have all the type information for the cell and model data).  And lastly, the `bridgedDataSource` returns a benign `UITableViewCell` which makes `UIKit` very happy and it has all the qualities I needed.  One of the fundamental concepts Andy relies upon is Decomposition.  I believe he has a YouTube video out there somewhere or maybe on his site there is a video where he walks through this.  I'll see if I can find it and update answer if I do.